# BLE Peripheral Connection Failure

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two devices: one of them is a Raspberry Pi 4B and the other is a Bluetooth AHRS IMU sensor Witmotion WT901BLECL.The Robust Acceleration, Angular velocity, Angle & Magnetic filed Detector.
I have this Python code, and when I run it, I encounter the following error.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this.

```
from bluepy.btle import UUID, Peripheral, DefaultDelegate
import time

class NotifyDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
            DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
    def handleNotification(self,cHandle,data):
        print("notify from "+str(cHandle)+str(data)+"\n")

p = Peripheral("FD:D4:23:B6:5D:DA").withDelegate(NotifyDelegate())

time.sleep(0.5)

dev = 0

for ser in p.getServices():
    print(str(ser))
    for chara in ser.getCharacteristics():
        print(str(chara))
        print("Handle is "+str(chara.getHandle()))
        print("properties is "+chara.propertiesToString())
        print("uuid is "+str(chara.uuid))
        if "0000ffe4" in str(chara.uuid):
            dev = chara
            dev.write("1", False)
            print("en")
        if(chara.supportsRead()):
            data = chara.read()
            print(type(data))
            print(len(data))
            print(data)
    print("\n")


try:
    while True:
        if dev:
            dev.write("1", True)
            print("en")
        if(dev.supportsRead()):
            data = dev.read()
            print(type(data))
            print(len(data))
            print(data)
        if p.waitForNotifications(1.0):
            # handleNotification() was called
            continue

        print ("Waiting...")
        # Perhaps do something else here
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print("except:",e)
    p.disconnect()
    exit(1)
finally:
    print("final print")
    p.disconnect()
    exit(1)

p.disconnect()
exit(1)
```

---

**The Error is:

```
****Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/Witmotion/Wit_ble.py", line 12, in <module>
    p = Peripheral("FD:D4:23:B6:5D:DA").withDelegate(NotifyDelegate())
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 391, in __init__
    self._connect(deviceAddr, addrType, iface)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 439, in _connect
    raise BTLEDisconnectError("Failed to connect to peripheral %s, addr type: %s" % (addr, addrType), rsp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError: Failed to connect to peripheral FD:D4:23:B6:5D:DA, addr type: public
```

I try to connect to the sensor and retrieve the raw data from it in real time

Comment: Can you scan the sensor with a generic Android app like [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp)?

Comment: Yes, I can
Also I can connect to it after scan